# Why do we need partitions in PostgresSQL? (or any other RDBMS)

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, rdbms

So, I am trying to teach myself partitions in PostgreSQL. I understand that a database can become slow when a table hits millions+ of lines and indexes don't fit into memory anymore.

One thing that strikes me is how partitions with sub-partitions resemble a lot to some kind of **manually managed indexes**. What is wrong with regular indexes? Why can't them partition themselves?

I imagine this must be hard, judging by the fact that this problem seems to have been around for a while. Maybe the DB cannot know how we plan to access our data? If so, why isn't there some simple way to tell the DB how we want to access our data?

**Why do we have to do the whole table inheritance dance when partitionning is such a common case?**

EDIT: There seem to be some work in progress to support a nicer syntax, Cf. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Table_partitioning

Comment: A sufficiently sophisticated system could transparently partition data up behind the scenes, but in practice that's hard to do. Partitions are really workarounds for insufficiently smart query planners, index combination, table layout management, etc. They help you reduce the impact of heavyweight lock operations, etc, but they're really mostly just a hack. In the case of PostgreSQL specifically, it doesn't really support partitioning, so we *emulate* it with hacks around table inheritance. It doesn't support it because it's hard to do and nobody's done the work yet.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is pretty much what I feared. Is there big caveats to using things like pg_partman or rails' Partitioned gem?

Comment: Yes. You can't have foreign keys referring to the parent table of partitions. Or rather, you can, but they'll be useless because they'll only "see" the values directly in the parent table (usually empty) not in the partitions. You get foreign keys or inheritance, pick one. There are also some fun issues around constraints and triggers on inherited tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A general goal in designing data storage and retrieval systems is that query time should scale with *the amount of data being retrieved*, not *the amount of data that exists in total*.  Partitioning is a powerful tool for achieving that goal.

Consider a table of session data that looks something like:

```
create table clickstream (
  clickstream_id bigserial primary key
, created timestamp default now() not null
, user_agent text
, client_ip inet
, entry_page text
, session_id text
--and so on...
);
```

Obviously you would have an index on `created` which would allow you to perform queries on a particular date/time range of the data.  If you get 10k sessions a day and you have 3 months of data online, querying for a day's worth of data works quite well.  If you get 1M sessions a day and you have 4 years of data online, this works poorly.

But why?  The nature of the I/O you're performing -- random reads -- doesn't scale well.  The query engine has to find the location in the `created` B-tree that corresponds to the start of your range, and likewise the end of your range, and traverse every element of the tree in between, and read each row individually.  Or rather, read each relevant *block* individually (since all I/O is at the block level), but many rows means many blocks, especially for wide tables.

What you would prefer to do is read all of those blocks *sequentially*, as in a full table scan.  In fact what if you are doing this kind of operation over and over again, you'll find yourself creating a temporary table with just the day's data and querying that instead, as an optimization.  This is the kind of optimization that partitioning let's the query engine do **automatically**.

Partition the table by day, and when you write (for example) `select ... from clickstream where created >= current_date-1 and created < current_date` the query engine will understand that this data falls entirely within one partition, and then compute that even if `created` is indexed on that partition that using said index is not worthwhile, and perform a much faster sequential scan.

Now, that's for an analytic workload.  Partitioning can also be valuable in a transactional workload, but in more limited ways.  Obviously if your transactional system is doing range scans in real-time then the exact same pattern can apply.  But it can also be useful to partition on certain keys.  For example if you have an `orders` table with a `customer_id`, and the nature of your business is such that most customers have *many* orders, and the `orders` table is *always* accessed using `customer_id`, you can divide the `orders` table into an arbitrary number of partitions, say 64, on a hash of `customer_id`.  This has the effect of reducing the overall table and index size when performing a query.  More of the rows in a particular block will be relevant, making read-ahead more effective. Partition-local B-trees will have fewer nodes, and therefore fewer blocks, and potentially even less depth.

**To get back to the heart of your question**, which if I understand it is "why do we have to do this at all?", the simple reality is that *YOU always know more about your data than the RDBMS does*.  This is the same reason query planners sometimes make mistakes.  Query planners can be supplied with better statistics, or given hints, but they're just not smart enough to wholesale restructure your data for you.  That is a high-level pattern recognition task that your brain is better suited to than any piece of code.  What's more, this kind of restructuring must be carefully considered and then implemented by hand.  I wouldn't even trust an RDBMS to automatically create indexes for me, much less rebuild the physical layout of a multi-terabyte table!

(One final note, PostgreSQL in particular *only sorta* supports partitioning. It's much easier to implement all of the above in an RDBMS like Oracle that supports it as a first-class construct.)

Comment: Very interesting answer! You are mentionning that "Partition-local B-trees will have fewer nodes, and therefore fewer blocks, and potentially even less depth". Ok, we have smaller indexes, but aren't we just shoveling this up into a flat-ish inheritance tree? Say we partition by some customer_id and sub-partition by created. How is that different from a btree index on (customer_id, created)?

Comment: The difference again is the *total* size.  With a composite index on (customer_id, created), when restricting both fields, it's true that the first-level search on customer_id will pare down the search space for created, but the index as a whole contains the whole search space. With a sub-partitioned table & index, the search space is pre-divided. Ideally this lets you full-scan instead of index-scan, but even if you have to use the index there are fewer possible blocks to read. (I won't claim this is an ideal solution. Like most optimizations, it's a bit of a hack, and sacrifices generality.)

Comment: Do you imply that the sum of the sizes of all partitions' indexes will be smaller than one big index on a non-partitioned table?

Comment: @Samuel In particular, partitioning can help improve [Locality of Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference), or more concretely boost your cache hit rate. If most of your "hot" data is in one or two partitions, it will help significantly that the index and heap blocks you are reading will likely be available in cache.

Comment: Maybe Postgres partitioning is better than Oracle in 2018? Or maybe not lulz